# Speeding up list search and inserts in c#

Tags: c#, performance, list, optimization

I have a legacy app that used to use small(er) sets of data.

Currently we're expanding it to run on a much bigger set of data (yay that always works well).

So now I have this piece of code.  `sValues` is a List of 21 million (yes) items. `sProcessedStatus` is a matching list to indicate whether we're going to use it or not (ie not -1 or -2), and if we are, we're adding them into `groupSourceVals`.  But we only add unique values, thus the `indexOf()` check.

```
for (int p = 0; p < sValues.Count; p++)
{
  int currentProcessed = sProcessedStatus[p];
  if ((!(currentProcessed == -1)) && (!(currentProcessed == -2)))
  {
    if (groupSourceVals.IndexOf(sValues[p]) == -1)
    {
      groupSourceVals.Add(sValues[p]);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Dropping non-processed value " + sValues[p]);
  }
}
```

However, on a 64 bit quad-core machine, this was seriously still running after several days.  Aside from multi-threading the sucker, any theories on speeding it up that I'm missing? Is IndexOf massively slow and is there a better alternative?

Comment: Is there a reason why your working with such a large dataset and not using a SQL database?

Comment: What is in `sValues`, is the list sorted?

Comment: Why are the statuses and values in separate collections?  They should probably be a single collection of a custom type with a status and value property.

Comment: @Servy - legacy.  Probably should be, but such is life.

Comment: @fastreload - it's not sorted no, it's a variety of string data.

Comment: Can you change groupSourceVals to a HashSet?  This would elimate the lookup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `HashSet<T>.Contains` for a fast O(1) existence check. Either only use only a `HashSet` or maintain both `List` and `HashSet` and keep them in sync.

Comment: Good grief it ran faster.  Like seconds compared with an estimate of 18 days.  I'll gladly accept this, thanks.